# unable to create a mlink in microsoft azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, kudu

I have taken Apache Tomcat 8 as azure app service, I have some customize application file which need a mlink(symbolic link) with war data files. can anyone have any idea on this as how to run mlink, as when I am trying to do it is asking for administrative privilege. tried with(kudo) web link(cmd and also with powershell)

msg: ser have no sufficient privilege to execute script. Run script with administrator privilege.

Comment: You won't get those privileges, so you'll have to find another way to do what you want.

Comment: will be great if you give some suggestions